# Convert date to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, date

Is there a built-in method for converting a `date` to a `datetime` in Python, for example getting the `datetime` for the midnight of the given date? The opposite conversion is easy: `datetime` has a `.date()` method.

Do I really have to manually call `datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)`?

Comment: Not a silly question; date objects should have a `.datetime()` method; what's silly is that they don't have such a method.

Comment: @Zags: or `datetime.from_date()` constructor.

Comment: no it shouldn't a date is a subset of datetime (it's even in the name). It's unambiguous what the date is from a datetime. But the other way round, a date is a block of 24h (usually), so it can have many datetimes. What datetime would come from a date? You can't always so 00:00 because what if that time doesn't exist, like for example daylight savings skipped it. Not so easy#

Comment: @Dalore Daylight savings time is between 1am and 2am to avoid exactly the problem you are describing.

Comment: @zags it all depends on the timezone source and destination, you can have a daylight savings time change at 1am but that would correspond to a midnight change in some other timezone. and if you're programming which timezone are you using? you could very well end up trying to get a time that doesn't exist. My point still stands, adding a time to a date is not straight forward. Then you also got to consider is your new datetime also timezone aware or naive.

Comment: Silly question: This problem might occurs when you parse date with a .date in the end as many example shows on this forum. Instead skip this .date() and you can directly do date comparisons like:
'''
import datetime.datetime
def is_date_earlier_than_date(d1, d2, parse_format)
    d1_time_obj = datetime.strptime(d1, parse_format)
    d2_time_obj = datetime.strptime(d2, parse_format)
    return d1_time_obj < d2_time_obj
'''

Comment: @dalore, wouldn't any other method used to construct a datetime from a date have the same issue?

Answer (score 1242, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.combine(date, time)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine); for the time, you create a `datetime.time` object initialized to midnight.

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time())
```

Comment: Thanks. Combined with the fact that time() returns (0,0) I think this comes out the cleanest: `datetime.combine(d, time())`

Comment: Just be careful not to let your code get datetime.time() confused with time.time().  Qualified names FTW!

Comment: Yes, good point. Fortunately, combine() raises an exception if you pass in a `time.time` or anything else other than a `datetime.time`.

Comment: For midnight, there's a python constant at either datetime.time.min (2.7.1+) or datetime.min.time() (older python)

Comment: @EMP, I've added an example using that technique. Let's hope it gets accepted.

Comment: Good solution, but I don't think datetime.min.time() is the cleanest way of getting a 00:00:00 time. That is because what it does is first retrieving the minimum value representable by datetime and then getting its time component. Incidentally, datetime.min = datetime(MINYEAR, 1, 1, tzinfo=None) and has a time of 00:00:00. However, I think it is cleaner to explicitly create a 00:00:00 time either through time.min or time(0, 0, 0, 0).

Comment: Why importing _date_ at all? `datetime.combine(datetime.today(), datetime.min.time())`

Comment: @el.atomo because the actual *question* didn't explicitly ask for just today

Comment: Timezone like this (with variables my_date & my_timezone) : `import datetime; datetime.datetime.combine(my_date, datetime.time(datetime.MINYEAR, 1, 1, tzinfo=my_timezone)`

Comment: I got error named: "AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'combine'"

Comment: @farisfath25 see that you didn't confuse the `datetime` library with the `datetime.datetime` object (event though it is confusing)

Comment: `from datetime import datetime, time; datetime.combine(d, time.min)` seems cleanest to me

Answer (score 215):

There are several ways, although I do believe the one you mention (and dislike) is the most readable one.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t=datetime.date.today()
>>> datetime.datetime.fromordinal(t.toordinal())
datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 20, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day)
datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 20, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime(*t.timetuple()[:-4])
datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 20, 0, 0)
```

and so forth -- but basically they all hinge on appropriately extracting info from the `date` object and ploughing it back into the suitable ctor or classfunction for `datetime`.

Comment: Very good point.  `datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)` does seem much more readable than the accepted answer `datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time())`.

Comment: @SimonTewsi:  `midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time.min)` seems cleaner (suggested by [`@`larham1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937622/convert-date-to-datetime-in-python#comment7273463_1937636))

Comment: @J. F. Sebastian: It is somewhat cleaner but I agree with Wes Winham in his answer that it requires the reader to know what datetime.time.min represents.  Whereas it seems to me that `datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)` is more obvious (a datetime without the time component).  It's a minor point, though, and using a variable name like "midnight" makes it obvious what the result is even if the reader doesn't know what `datetime.time.min` represents.

Comment: @SimonTewsi: note: [`datetime(d.year, d.mont, d.day)` is not only more obvious, it is faster too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33276464/4279).

Comment: Another variant just for fun: `datetime.datetime(*(getattr(d, attr) for attr in ("year", "month", "day")))`. That way, you can easily modify the list of attributes that matter to you. Hours could be added dynamically for example.

Comment: `d = d.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)` is possible too but I hate this approach as it forces you to know all the keywords and set them to 0 manually. It works for 4 parameters, but if there was 12 we would start to question this approach.

Answer (score 131):

The accepted answer is correct, but I would prefer to avoid using `datetime.min.time()` because it's not obvious to me exactly what it does. If it's obvious to you, then more power to you. I also feel the same way about the `timetuple` method and the reliance on the ordering.

In my opinion, the most readable, explicit way of doing this without relying on the reader to be very familiar with the `datetime` module API is:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
today = date.today()
today_with_time = datetime(
    year=today.year, 
    month=today.month,
    day=today.day,
)
```

That's my take on "explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: And a hat tip to Kyle Gibson for the original idea: http://stackoverflow.com/users/513197/kyle-gibson

Comment: I agree with your sentiment.  All these other answers with timetuple and asterisks and min.time() require research, and the Python way of handling dates and datetimes is a bit cumbersome anyway compared to the ease that Microsoft handles them in VBA.  It as simple as wrapping them in hash symbols in that language.  But I digress.

Comment: This works, but you may need the `datetime` to be timezone aware. In which case, you can `import pytz` and then add `tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/London')`, for example.

Comment: Since 3.6, simply use [`< naive datetime >.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) for **local** timezone adjustments. Since [3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#zoneinfo), handling specific timezones got even easier, just leverage `zoneinfo` like this: `from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo; datetime(year=..., month=..., day=..., tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/London'))`. No need of external dependencies!

Answer (score 58):

You can use the `date.timetuple()` method and unpack operator `*`.

```
args = d.timetuple()[:6]
datetime.datetime(*args)
```

Comment: This is useful for my situation. I don't know if it's a date or a datetime I'm being passed, and it's not very pythonic to check which class it is. This method looks like it will work for both datetime and date objects.

Comment: I used to use this before discovering `datetime.combine` via @kiamlaluno's answer. I think it's fairly pythonic, especially given constructing a `datetime.time` object is likely to look something like `datetime.time(*map(int,"H:M:S".split(":")))` anyway...

Comment: useful in many other contexts too for example truncating seconds, minutes, or hours by indexing down to as low as [:3] and even lower if you pad with + (n,) as in : `dt.datetime(*(dt.datetime.utcnow().timetuple()[:2] + (1, )))`

Comment: Nice approach, for convenience here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple) for `timetuple()`

Answer (score 11):

you can also use

```
date = datetime.utcnow().date()
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(date.isoformat())

print(dt)
```

> datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 15, 0, 0)

Comment: You can even add the time as a string in this way: `datetime.fromisoformat(date.isoformat() + ' 17:32')`

Answer (score 10):

Today being 2016, I think the cleanest solution is provided by pandas Timestamp:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
d = date.today()
pd.Timestamp(d)
```

Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of datetime and is interchangable with it in most cases. Check:

```
from datetime import datetime
isinstance(pd.Timestamp(d), datetime)
```

But in case you really want a vanilla datetime, you can still do:

```
pd.Timestamp(d).to_datetime()
```

Timestamps are a lot more powerful than datetimes, amongst others when dealing with timezones. Actually, Timestamps are so powerful that it's a pity they are so poorly documented...

Comment: Good call. Came here as I thought it would need a python datetime solution to a pandas DatetimeIndex issue. Shame pandas doesn't have the concept of a DateIndex.

Comment: why do we require a heavyweight package just to do datetime manipulation, even in 2016?!

Comment: Bringing out pandas for this is like taking a hammer to an ant

Comment: using pandas to solve this problem is major overkill

Comment: `to_datetime()` has been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Timestamp.to_datetime.html), so use `to_pydatetime()` instead.

This is a good answer for those that already have to use Pandas for reasons and need datetime format as well.

Comment: −1. Not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

One way to convert from date to datetime that hasn't been mentioned yet:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
d = date.today()
datetime.strptime(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'), '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: True, but converting ints to strings and back is probably rather more expensive than working directly with ints, so I'd only use this one for low-volume processing

Answer (score 4):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_datetime = date_converter.date_to_datetime(my_date)
```

Disclosure: I'm the owner of the package.

Comment: You should explicitly disclose that this is your own package.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I really have to manually call datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)

No, you'd rather like to call

```
date_to_datetime(dt)
```

which you can implement once in some `utils/time.py` in your project:

```
from typing import Optional
from datetime import date, datetime

def date_to_datetime(
    dt: date,
    hour: Optional[int] = 0,
    minute: Optional[int] = 0, 
    second: Optional[int] = 0) -> datetime:

    return datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, hour, minute, second)
```

Comment: Probably an idea to add tz to that

Comment: better, as this will be quicker than converting to string and back

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `toisoformat`/`fromisoformat`: you can use `date.toordinal` and `datetime.fromordinal`:

```py
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(1991, 2, 20)
start_date_midnight = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(start_date.toordinal())
```

I suspect this is more efficient than converting to/from a string.

You can test this process as so:

```py
def test_datetime_from_date():
    for x in range(1,1000000):
        date_ = datetime.date.fromordinal(x)
        datetime_ = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(date_.toordinal())
        datetime_iso_date, t, datetime_iso_time = datetime_.isoformat().partition("T")
        assert datetime_iso_date == date_.isoformat()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `dt` timezone aware datetime (with Django timezone util):

```
from django.utils import timezone


timezone.now().replace(*(*dt.timetuple()[:6], 0))
```