# How to truncate the time on a datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime

What is a classy way to way truncate a python `datetime` object?

In this particular case, to the day. So basically setting hour, minute, seconds, and microseconds to 0.

I would like the output to also be a `datetime` object, not a string.

Answer (score 542, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) # Returns a copy
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 29, 0, 0)
```

But if you really don't care about the time aspect of things, then you should really only be passing around `date` objects...

```
>>> d_truncated = datetime.date(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)
>>> d_truncated
datetime.date(2011, 3, 29)
```

Comment: With a timezone-aware dt, datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day) throws away the tzinfo information.

Comment: if you're looking for just today, you can also do datetime.date.today()

Comment: Note that python 2 and python 3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) both state that the `replace()` method _returns_ a datetime object, so the correct incantation would be:
`dt = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

Comment: OP wants `datetime`, not `date` object (that you could get using `dt.date()` call (no need to use the explicit constructor)). The `.replace()` method may fail if [`datetime` adds nanosecond support](http://bugs.python.org/issue15443). You could [use `datetime.combine()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28311227/4279).

Comment: @chrisw Why not just write it up in one line `datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)` ?

Answer (score 97):

Use a `date` not a `datetime` if you dont care about the time.

```
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.date()
datetime.date(2011, 3, 29)
```

You can update a datetime like this:

```
>>> now.replace(minute=0, hour=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 29, 0, 0)
```

Comment: With timezone-aware datetimes, now.date() throws away the tzinfo information.

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ: here's how you could [get the timezone-aware midnight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236372/4279)

Comment: Note that it’s kind of a pain [to convert it back to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1937622/812102), though.

Answer (score 52):

### Four years later: another way, avoiding `replace`

I know the accepted answer from four years ago works, but this seems a tad lighter than using `replace`:

```
dt = datetime.date.today()
dt = datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)
```

**Notes**

- When you create a `datetime` object without passing time properties to the constructor, you get midnight.
- As others have noted, this assumes you want a datetime object for later use with timedeltas.
- You can, of course, substitute this for the first line: `dt = datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: With timezone-aware datetimes, tzinfo information does not share between the two.

Answer (score 27):

To get a midnight corresponding to a given datetime object, you could use [`datetime.combine()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, time
>>> dt = datetime.utcnow()
>>> dt.date()
datetime.date(2015, 2, 3)
>>> datetime.combine(dt, time.min)
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 0, 0)
```

The advantage compared to [the `.replace()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476114/4279) is that `datetime.combine()`-based solution will continue to work even if [`datetime` module introduces the nanoseconds support](http://bugs.python.org/issue15443).

`tzinfo` can be preserved if necessary but the utc offset may be different at midnight e.g., due to a DST transition and therefore a naive solution (setting `tzinfo` time attribute) may fail. See [How do I get the UTC time of “midnight” for a given timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236372/4279)

Comment: and it saves you a lot of typing (compared to replace()).

Answer (score 26):

You cannot truncate a datetime object because [it is immutable](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#available-types).

However, here is one way to construct a new datetime with 0 hour, minute, second, and microsecond fields, without throwing away the original date or tzinfo:

```
newdatetime = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Comment: +1: if you put the `replace` option first, since that's probably what they want.

Comment: It is incorrect to use `tzinfo=now.tzinfo`. The `tzinfo` at midnight may be different e.g., utc offset at `2012-04-01 00:09:00` (9am) in Australia/Melbourne timezone is `AEST+10:00` but it is `AEDT+11:00` at `2012-04-01 00:00:00` (midnight) -- there is end-of-DST transition on that day. You could use `pytz` module to fix it, see my answer.

Answer (score 16):

See more at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html

It's now 2019, I think the most efficient way to do it is:

```
df['truncate_date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('d')
```

Comment: yeah, let's use dt.floor!!

Comment: Waw, exactly what I've been looking for the last three hours. Thanks a lot. That's the only solution that enables to pass the truncating frequency as a parameter...

Comment: Well, `df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('d')` will not work. Column name must be different and this is a serious drawback.

Comment: This only works in the context of pandas (not Python datetime), but it's a great solution in that context.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for that (although it could be overhead for that task). You could use [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.round.html), [floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) and [ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.ceil.html) like for usual numbers and any pandas frequency from [offset-aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
pd_now = pd.Timestamp(now)

freq = '1d'
pd_round = pd_now.round(freq)
dt_round = pd_round.to_pydatetime()

print(now)
print(dt_round)

"""
2018-06-15 09:33:44.102292
2018-06-15 00:00:00
"""
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a great library used to manipulate dates: [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)

```
import datetime
from delorean import Delorean
now = datetime.datetime.now()
d = Delorean(now, timezone='US/Pacific')

>>> now    
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 26, 19, 46, 40, 525703)

>>> d.truncate('second')
Delorean(datetime=2015-03-26 19:46:40-07:00, timezone='US/Pacific')

>>> d.truncate('minute')
Delorean(datetime=2015-03-26 19:46:00-07:00, timezone='US/Pacific')

>>> d.truncate('hour')
Delorean(datetime=2015-03-26 19:00:00-07:00, timezone='US/Pacific')

>>> d.truncate('day')
Delorean(datetime=2015-03-26 00:00:00-07:00, timezone='US/Pacific')

>>> d.truncate('month')
Delorean(datetime=2015-03-01 00:00:00-07:00, timezone='US/Pacific')

>>> d.truncate('year')
Delorean(datetime=2015-01-01 00:00:00-07:00, timezone='US/Pacific')
```

and if you want to get datetime value back:

```
>>> d.truncate('year').datetime
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: it returns the wrong time (wrong utc offset) if the result time has a different utc offset e.g., due to a DST transition. See [How do I get the UTC time of “midnight” for a given timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236372/4279)

Answer (score 3):

You can use datetime.strftime to extract the day, the month, the year...

Example :

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.today()

# Retrieves the day and the year
print d.strftime("%d-%Y")
```

Output (for today):

```
29-2011
```

If you just want to retrieve the day, you can use day attribute like :

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.today()

# Retrieves the day
print d.day
```

Ouput (for today):

```
29
```

Comment: Well the thing is I already do this once, so that might have more overhead then just setting the hour min etc fields in the datetime object.

Comment: Heh, thats a weird way to do it, you can actually just do `d.day` etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with a Series of type DateTime there is a more efficient way to truncate them, specially when the Series object has a lot of rows.

You can use the [floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) function

For example, if you want to truncate it to hours:

Generate a range of dates

```
times = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018 04:00:00', end='1/1/2018 22:00:00', freq='s'))
```

We can check it comparing the running time between the replace and the floor functions.

```
%timeit times.apply(lambda x : x.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))
>>> 341 ms ± 18.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit times.dt.floor('h')
>>>>2.26 ms ± 451 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: this answer is the best but got only 1 upvote, so I upvoted your answer:)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime.date(dt)
datetime.date(2019, 4, 2)
```

Comment: This is the best if you don't care about getting a datetime.datetime object back and just want a date.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another way which fits in one line but is not particularly elegant:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to truncate to an arbitrary timedelta:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
truncate = lambda t, d: t + (datetime.min - t) % - d
# 2022-05-04 15:54:19.979349
now = datetime.now()

# truncates to the last 15 secondes
print(truncate(now, timedelta(seconds=15)))
# truncates to the last minute
print(truncate(now, timedelta(minutes=1)))
# truncates to the last 2 hours
print(truncate(now, timedelta(hours=2)))
# ...

"""
2022-05-04 15:54:15
2022-05-04 15:54:00
2022-05-04 14:00:00
"""
```

PS: This is for python3

Answer (score 1):

There is a module datetime_truncate which handlers this for you. It just calls datetime.replace.

Answer (score 1):

6 years later... I found this post and I liked more the numpy aproach:

```
import numpy as np
dates_array = np.array(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-15', '2013-01-30']).astype('datetime64[ns]')
truncated_dates = dates_array.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by specifying `isoformat`

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds', sep=' ')
2022-11-24 12:42:05
```

The documentation offers more details about the `isoformat()` usage.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
datetime.date.today()
```

It's light and returns exactly what you want.

Comment: The same answer has been given before, there is nothing new.

Comment: Sorry @slfan but i didn't see any post with your name, even using "search" from browser.

Comment: Not by me, by zx81 3 years ago. search for datetime.date.today(). If an answer is correct, you should upvote, not answer again.

Comment: cast as datetime