# Display Python datetime without time

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a date string and want to convert it to the date type:

I have tried to use `datetime.datetime.strptime` with the format that I want but it is returning the time with the conversion.

```
when = alldates[int(daypos[0])]
print when, type(when)

then = datetime.datetime.strptime(when, '%Y-%m-%d')
print then, type(then)
```

This is what the output returns:

```
2013-05-07 <type 'str'>
2013-05-07 00:00:00 <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I need to remove the time: `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
print then.date()
```

What you want is a datetime.date object. What you have is a datetime.datetime object. You can either change the object when you print as per above, or do the following when creating the object:

```
then = datetime.datetime.strptime(when, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Comment: Look here for keeping the datetime format: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476065/how-to-truncate-the-time-on-a-datetime-object-in-python)

Answer (score 11):

If you need the result to be timezone-aware, you can use the `replace()` method of `datetime` objects.  This preserves timezone, so you can do

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> now = timezone.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 30, 14, 15, 43, 726252, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 30, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Note that this returns a *new* datetime object -- `now` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> print then.date(), type(then.date())
2013-05-07 <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert a string into a date, the easiest way AFAIK is the dateutil module:

```
import dateutil.parser
datetime_object = dateutil.parser.parse("2013-05-07")
```

It can also handle time zones:

```
print(dateutil.parser.parse("2013-05-07"))
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 7, 1, 12, 12, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

If you have a datetime object, say:

```
import pytz
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.UTC)
```

and you want chop off the time part, then I think it is easier to construct a new object instead of "substracting the time part". It is shorter and more bullet proof:

```
date_part datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, tzinfo=now.tzinfo)
```

It also keeps the time zone information, it is easier to read and understand than a timedelta substraction, and you also have the option to give a different time zone in the same step (which makes sense, since you will have zero time part anyway).

Answer (score 1):

For me, I needed to KEEP a timetime object because I was using UTC and it's a bit of a pain. So, this is what I ended up doing:

```
date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

start_of_day = date - datetime.timedelta(
    hours=date.hour, 
    minutes=date.minute, 
    seconds=date.second, 
    microseconds=date.microsecond
)

end_of_day = start_of_day + datetime.timedelta(
    hours=23, 
    minutes=59, 
    seconds=59
)
```

Example output:

```
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 14, 17, 21, 5, 511600)
>>> start_of_day
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 14, 0, 0)
>>> end_of_day
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 14, 23, 59, 59)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want a `datetime` and not a `date` but want the time zero'd out you could combine `date` with `datetime.min.time()`

Example:

```py
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today().date(),
                          datetime.datetime.min.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `pd.to_datetime(then)` and pandas will convert the date elements into ISO date format- `[YYYY-MM-DD]`.

You can pass this as map/apply to use it in a dataframe/series too.

Answer (score 0):

You can usee the following code:
`week_start = str(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=datetime.today().weekday() % 7)).split(' ')[0]`

Comment: I think the question was not about week_start. It was more about displaying a date without the time.