# Pandas Datetime Formatting

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Currently my dates are formatted as a string.  I was able to get the string converted to date time using the following:

```
df['submitted_on'] = df['submitted_on'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

I would like to remove the time stamp, but I am having an awfully difficult time doing so.  My preferred format is `%Y%m%d`.  So I stumbled upon [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153795/python-remove-time-from-datetime-string) page and added `.date()`.  Resulting in below:

```
df['submitted_on'] = df['submitted_on'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d').date())
```

I am getting this value error and I am again lost at what to do to drop the time stamp.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

> ValueError: time data '2015-02-26 16:45:36.0' does not match format '%Y%m%d'

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series(['2010-01-01 10:00', '2010-06-01 11:00'])

pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(s).dt.date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `normalize` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html)).

```
dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='today', periods=4, freq='D')
dti
```

outputs

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-08-04 14:30:34.447589', '2016-08-05 14:30:34.447589',
               '2016-08-06 14:30:34.447589', '2016-08-07 14:30:34.447589'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

And

```
dti.normalize()
```

outputs

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-08-04', '2016-08-05', '2016-08-06', '2016-08-07'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

If it's a Series of Timestamps you can convert them with map.

Edit: @piRSquared's way is better in this case.

```
pd.to_datetime(dti).map(lambda dt: dt.date())
```

outputs

```
array([datetime.date(2016, 8, 4), datetime.date(2016, 8, 5),
       datetime.date(2016, 8, 6), datetime.date(2016, 8, 7)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Is it practical to apply dti.normalize() to my entire dataframe or should I only normalize datetime columns?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the `Timestamp` object to `datetime.datetime` object and extract the `datetime.date` part as shown:

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: print(pd.Timestamp('2015-02-26 16:45:36.0').to_datetime().date())
2015-02-26
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Your desired format:

```
In [11]: print(pd.Timestamp('2015-02-26 16:45:36.0').to_datetime().date().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
20150226
<class 'str'>
```