# How to select date and hour in the list of datetime in Python 3.5

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of datetime containing year,month,day,hour,min,second and tzinfo, such as

```
In [1]:TimeCreate[0:4]
Out[1]:
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 27, 2),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2)]
```

I only want to select date and hour in the datetime, therefore, I can have the first three items as one class, i.e, I can summarize the number of repetition under each hour. How could I obtain the following format?

```
In [2]:TimeCreate[0:4]
Out[2]:
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Therefore, I can have information, such as 3 repetition at hour 0.
Thank very much

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476065/truncate-python-datetime ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace),

```
import datetime

list_dt = [ datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2),
            datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2),
            datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 27, 2),
            datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2)] 

adjust_dt = [dt.replace(minute=0, second=0) for dt in list_dt]
```

---

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the frequency,

```
import collections

count = collections.Counter(adjust_dt)

print(count)
# Output
Counter({datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 1, 0): 1})
```

Comment: Thanks @sparkandshine, I created two-way table which gave the record for the repetition of a specific categorical variable (my object) under each hour from 01/01/2011 to 12/31/2015 by your solution.

Answer (score 0):

## you can extract anything from datetime.datetime class

import datetime

obj = datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2)

print(obj.day, obj.hour)