# pandas: subtracting current date from the date in a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, subtraction

I am attempting to calculate the difference in days between todays and a pandas data consisting of historical data. Below is the intended code:

```
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime( df['date']) - pd.datetime.now().date()
```

However, it produces the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and
>   'datetime.date'

The date column in the pandas table looks like this:

```
0       2018-12-18
1       2018-12-18
2       2018-12-18
3       2018-12-18
4       2018-12-18
```

How do I fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime( df['date'])  - pd.datetime.now();
Please try this one

Comment: @MadhuriPatel, That's incorrect, since `now` includes time components and this isn't what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to subtract same types - **datetimes** with **datetime** (with zero times) or **dates** with **date**.

Use [`Timestamp.now`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.now.html) with [`Timestamp.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html) or [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) for remove `time`s:

```
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime( df['date']) - pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() 

df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime( df['date']) - pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d')
```

You can also use [`replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476166):

```
dt = pd.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime( df['date']) - dt
```

Or convert `Datetimes` to [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)s for subtract same types:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now().date()
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date - dt
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2018-04-03', periods=10, freq='100D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng}) 

df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime( df['date']) - pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() 
print (df)
        date      diff
0 2018-04-03 -261 days
1 2018-07-12 -161 days
2 2018-10-20  -61 days
3 2019-01-28   39 days
4 2019-05-08  139 days
5 2019-08-16  239 days
6 2019-11-24  339 days
7 2020-03-03  439 days
8 2020-06-11  539 days
9 2020-09-19  639 days
```

Comment: This does not work. Produces error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: @Garglesoap What is your pandas version and what code failed for you?

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle but important distinction. Pandas supports **[`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)** objects but does **not** support **[`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date)** objects:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date'
df['date'] - date.today()

# works correctly
df['date'] - datetime.now()

# works correctly
df['date'] - datetime.now().replace(minute=0, hour=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Note [`pd.Timestamp.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.date.html) returns a `datetime.date` object. The docs do specify this: `Return date object with same year, month and day`. That `date` object is **not** supported natively by Pandas in the same way `datetime` objects are supported.

But replacing time values is cumbersome. You will likely prefer using in-built Pandas methods for your calculations. These are all equivalent:

```
df['date'] - pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D')
df['date'] - pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()
df['date'] - pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
```