# How to filter Timestamp in Hours instead of Seconds?

Tags: pyspark, timestamp, sampling, azure-databricks

[timestampbefore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEKvP.jpg) [timestamp after @pissall's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl3XP.jpg) I have a Timestamp column with 0.5Hz frequency, that results in millions of rows. I am willing to reduce this data size by having a timestamp in an hourly manner. i.e 24 observations for a particular day. 
I already reduced the data size by filtering the data by year, month and day. but as it is still very big i want to reduce it now to hourly basis.

I am working on Databricks and using PySpark for the same.

i used following command to reduce my data size from years to a Day.

`df = df.filter(df.Timestamp.between('2019-09-03 00:00:00','2019-09-04 00:00:00'))`

I would appreciate your help. 
Thanks

[Java.util.gregori...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J60a6.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to aggregate to hours?

Comment: @pissall yes exactly i want to aggregate data to hours.

Comment: What would the aggregations be? sum/avg/etc?

Comment: @pissall not really the sum/avg kind of aggregation. Instead, i want to fetch (aggregate) the values that occur every hour instead of every seconds. 
for example: 
`Time Stamp                    Latitude        Longitude`
`2019-09-03 00:00:00      132323         -3,54545`
`2019-09-03 00:00:01          xxxx            yyyy`
`2019-09-03 00:00:02          aaa              aaa`

instead of that i want to have values at 
`2019-09-03 00:00:00
2019-09-03 01:00:00
2019-09-03 02:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can `replace` the `minutes` and `seconds` part of your `datetime` using a UDF. Might not be the best solution, but here you go:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

date_replace_udf = F.udf(lambda date: date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0),TimestampType())

df = df.withColumn("Timestamp", date_replace_udf(F.col("Timestamp")))
```

Another reference: [How to truncate the time on a DateTime object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476065/how-to-truncate-the-time-on-a-datetime-object-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for a quick solution, but still it is returning data frame with a timestamp changing every second and not every hour.

Comment: Can you show the output? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @LavMehta You need to check `fixed_date` column. I'm editing my answer, please try again

Comment: thanks for the correction, but now i am getting "java.util.Gregori...."  under column Timestamp

Comment: it's not throwing an Error instead that's only what i can see in the column. Please check the image i added in the question.

Comment: `date_replace_udf = F.udf(lambda date: date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0),TimestampType())`
this way it helped to tackle Java.util.Gregori problem in Column.

Comment: @LavMehta Updated my answer. Please select and upvote if helped

Comment: The number of rows are still not reduced, now it is showing minutes and seconds as 00 and hour non zero, but then i have multiple rows with same hour. 

`2019-09-03 04:00:00` 
`2019-09-03 04:00:00`

Comment: @LavMehta for that you'll have to go an aggregationlike sum/mean/max etc