# Cannot remove timestamp in datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this date column which the `dtype: object` and the format is `31-Mar-20`. So i tried to turn it with `datetime.strptime` into `datetime64[D]` **and** with format of `2020-03-31`  which somehow whatever i have tried it does not work, i have tried some methode from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476065/how-to-truncate-the-time-on-a-datetime-object-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852911/how-do-i-convert-dates-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-date-data-type). In some way, it does turn my column to `datetime64` but it has timestamp in it and i don't want it. I need it to be `datetime` **without timestamp and the format** is `2020-03-31` This is my code

```
dates =  [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts,'%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
          for ts in df['date']]
df['date']= pd.DataFrame({'date': dates})
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach might work -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['20-Mar-2020', '21-Mar-2020', '22-Mar-2020']})
df
     dates
0  20-Mar-2020
1  21-Mar-2020
2  22-Mar-2020

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d-%b-%Y').dt.date
df
    dates
0  2020-03-20
1  2020-03-21
2  2020-03-22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d-%b-%y")
```

This converts it to a datetime, when you look at `df` it displays values as `2020-03-31` like you want, however these are all datetime objects so if you extract one value with `df['date'][0]` then you see `Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00')`

if you want to convert them into a date you can do

```
df['date'] = [df_datetime.date() for df_datetime in df['date'] ]
```

There is probably a better way of doing this step.