# Python: most efficient way to convert date to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

In Python, I convert a `date` to `datetime` by:

1. converting from `date` to `string`
2. converting from `string` to `datetime`

Code:

```
import datetime
dt_format="%d%m%Y"
my_date = datetime.date.today()
datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date.strftime(dt_format), dt_format)
```

I suspect this is far from the most efficient way to do this. What is the most efficient way to convert a date to datetime in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to datetime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937622/convert-date-to-datetime-in-python)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.combine()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) with a time object, `datetime.time.min` represents `00:00` and would match the output of your date-string-datetime path:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(my_date, datetime.time.min)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> my_date = datetime.date.today()
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(my_date, datetime.time.min)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 27, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937622/convert-date-to-datetime-in-python), this might be more readable:

```
datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day)
```