# Python Convert date to datetime directly

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a `date` object in Python and I want to convert it to `datetime` object with one simple step.

There is some not interesting solution like

`datetime.datetime(my_date.year, my_date.month, my_date.day)`

but I want a better way to solve this.

Comment: Why not like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661013/python-most-efficient-way-to-convert-date-to-datetime

Comment: If you don't like the verbosity of your current solution, write a small function. Unfortunately there's not really a better way (see linked duplicate question).

Comment: How are you acquiring this `datetime.date` object? Perhaps that code could be changed to return a `datetime.datetime` instead?

Comment: Yeah, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661013/python-most-efficient-way-to-convert-date-to-datetime is the answer. Thanks @sshashank124