# Convert Date to Datetime

Tags: django, date, datetime

I have a Date object and want to easily convert it to DateTime object, setting the time to an arbitrary value (e.g. 12:00:00).

I know it is possible taking the string and fiddleing with [strptime and strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

I am curious if there is a easier, direct way to do that.

Comment: Django is just a python web framework, so this may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937622/convert-date-to-datetime-in-python

Comment: See [Convert date to datetime in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1937636/3096768). Don't forget that Django is just Python!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to datetime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937622/convert-date-to-datetime-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be done using datetime.combine(date, time), like suggested in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1937636/3199774

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
d = date.today()
datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time())
```

Comment: what timezone is the result in? you should probably use django.utils.timezone.make_aware which has explicit handling for that