# Django: Changing UTC to timezone aware using template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have `start_date` of DateField() which is in utc.I want to convert it to timezone aware object
I tried writing

```
 {{ start_date|timezone:'Asia/Calcutta' }}
```

It displays nothing.Is timezone only for DateTimeField()?How can I use it on DateField().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, this only works for `datetime` objects (s. https://github.com/django/django/blob/abaf0ab4a444977dc8ac07b9b63256814c352245/django/templatetags/tz.py#L46)

As far as I know, there's no real way to make a `date` object timezone-aware. You can convert a `date` object to `datetime` though (s. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1937636/246028)

If you tell us what you're trying to achieve by making a date timezone-aware, I can try to amend my answer.