# logical indexing in pandas dataframe with timestamp column and datetime.date-object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I'm a little lost. I have a dataframe with a column names `dates`, that looks like this:

```
>>> dates_df
    product   tile       date
0       L30  34JDN 2019-01-01
1       L30  34JDN 2019-01-10
2       L30  34JDN 2019-01-17
3       L30  34JDN 2019-01-26
4       L30  34JDN 2019-02-02
..      ...    ...        ...
175     L30  34JEP 2019-11-17
176     L30  34JEP 2019-11-26
177     L30  34JEP 2019-12-03
178     L30  34JEP 2019-12-12
179     L30  34JEP 2019-12-28
```

I also have a single object of `<class 'datetime.date'>` that looks like this:

```
>>> date_np
datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
```

When I get the first element of the column `date` with `dates_df["date"][0]` it gives me: 
`Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')`.

How can I make this timestamp and my `date_np`-object comparable so that this would run

`dates_df[dates_df["date"] == date_np]`, because at the moment it gives me back an empty dataframe.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [product, tile, date]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for compare by scalar dates:

```
dates_df[dates_df["date"].dt.date == date_np]
```

Or convert scalar to [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1937629/2901002):

```
dates_df[dates_df["date"] == datetime(date_np.year, date_np.month, date_np.day)]
```