# How to convert date to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
def func(y, m):
for i in range(1, calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1]+1):
    th_date = date(y, m, i)
    print(th_date)
func(2020,4)
```

Note:
i am getting dates as date format i want to convert it into datetime i don't want time

Comment: Give us an example of input and output please, I dont understand what you mean by "I dont want time".

Comment: Why would you want to convert to a datetime object if you're not interested in the time?

Comment: Best answer I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69964767/2259496

Answer (score 0):

You might just use `datetime` in place of `date` as 4th and following arguments to [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) are optional, so

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2022,6,2)
print(dt)
```

gives output

```
2022-06-02 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in time but you want to use the *datetime* module then you can use the *date* class. For example:

```
from datetime import date

def func(year, month, day=1):
    return date(year, month, day)

print(func(2022, 4))
```

**Output:**

```
2022-04-01
```