Lookup by datetime in timestamp index does not work
Consider a date-indexed DataFrame:
d0 = datetime.date(2024,5,5)
d1 = datetime.date(2024,5,10)
df0 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[10,None],"c":list("xy")}, index=[d0,d1])
df0.index
Index([2024-05-05, 2024-05-10], dtype='object')

Note that df0.index.dtype is object.
Now, lookup works for date:
df0.loc[d0]
a       1
b    10.0
c       x
Name: 2024-05-05, dtype: object

but both df0.loc[str(d0)] and df0.loc[pd.Timestamp(d0)] raise KeyError.
This seems to be reasonable.
However, consider
df1 = df0.reindex(pd.date_range(d0,d1))
df1.index
DatetimeIndex(['2024-05-05', '2024-05-06', '2024-05-07', '2024-05-08',
               '2024-05-09', '2024-05-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

Note that df1.index.dtype is datetime64.
Now, lookup works for both df1.loc[pd.Timestamp(d0)] (as expected) and df1.loc[str(d0)] (why?!) but not for df1.loc[d0] (if it works for a string, why not date?!)
Is this the expected behavior (a bug with tenure)? Is this intentional?
PS. Reported.

d0 is a datetime.date while the range gives you pandas.Timestamps()...

@JonSG: yes, but if a string is auto-converted to Timestamp, why not date?!

Looking at the source code it's how pandas implements .loc for DateTimeIndex:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9cdd2ee5a58015ef6f4d15c7226110c9aab8140/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py#L596

It's implemented for:

datetime.datetime and np.datetime64 - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9cdd2ee5a58015ef6f4d15c7226110c9aab8140/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py#L211C28-L211C51
str
datetime.timedelta - raises TypeError
datetime.time

But NOT for datetime.date

The question is why - is it a simple oversight or a conscious design decision?

@sds I'm not sure, probably has something to do that it's DatetimeIndex (note the time). If you convert the index df1.index = df1.index.date then df1.loc[d0] works as expected (as you've shown in first example). But pandas is generally hostile to python builtin datetime module (they have their own Timestamp class)

yes, but then the index type is object,  and str and Timestamp no longer work...

@sds As a workaround, you can covert date to datetime, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1937629/10035985

How is it better than converting it to pd.Timestamp?  pd.Timestamp(x) is the shortest! ;-)

@sds every option is horrible IMHO ;)
